# How to sum occurences across multiple tables in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, count, aggregate-functions

I have, say, 2 tables

- `UK_Order` and `UK_Order_Item`
- `F_Order` and `F_Order_Item`

`UK_Order` (and F_Order) has the fields: `Id`, `orderStatus`.
`UK_Order_Item` (and F_Order_Item) has the fields: `orderId`, `model`, and `order_quantity`.

I'm trying to write the SQL to return the total number of different models sold through out the UK and F but can't.  So far I've come up with:

```
SELECT model, SUM(order_quantity) AS quantityOrdered 
FROM uk_order_item 
WHERE orderId 
IN
(
    SELECT Id FROM uk_order WHERE orderStatus = 'Incomplete'
)
GROUP BY model
```

and also

```
SELECT model, SUM(order_quantity) AS quantitySold
FROM f_order_item 
WHERE orderId 
IN
(
    SELECT Id FROM f_order WHERE orderStatus = 'Incomplete'
)
GROUP BY model
```

returning eg:

```
Model, QuantityOrdered
Volkswagen, 3
Ford, 2
Citroen, 4
...
```

and then to find the total number of volkwagens sold in the UK and F, I have to do a little bit calcluation (ie volkswagenCount = uk's volkwagen's quantitySold + F's volkwagen's quantitySold

In other words, my separate queries return the total models sold for the UK, and F(rance) - I would repeat this query for Germany, Spain etc. But is there a way of returning the total number for each model sold throughout Europe (UK, France, Germany etc.)?

Comment: Could you include `CREATE TABLE` statements? That'd be much better then describing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### DB design

I would rethink your db design. Unified tables including  all countries would probably be a better idea. So you would have single tables for all countries:

```
order_item 
order
```

Just add a `country_id` to table `order`.

#### Simpler query

The `IN` construct is needlessly complex. Simpler and faster:

```
SELECT oi.model, sum(oi.order_quantity) AS quantity_ordered 
FROM   uk_order      o
JOIN   uk_order_item oi ON oi.orderid = o.id
WHERE  o.orderstatus = 'Incomplete'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

While you have separate tables, nothing will be much simpler or faster than adding up separate counts:

```
SELECT model, sum(quantity_ordered) AS total_quantity_ordered
FROM  (
   SELECT model, sum(order_quantity) AS quantity_ordered
   FROM   uk_order      o
   JOIN   uk_order_item oi ON oi.orderid = o.id
   WHERE  o.orderstatus = 'Incomplete'
   GROUP  BY 1

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT model, sum(order_quantity) AS quantity_ordered
   FROM   f_order       o
   JOIN   f_order_item  oi ON oi.orderid = o.id
   WHERE  o.orderstatus = 'Incomplete'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

You *could* just merge rows it into a single derived table with `UNION ALL` before summing:

```
SELECT model, sum(quantity_ordered) AS total_quantity_ordered
FROM  (
   SELECT model, order_quantity AS quantity_ordered
   FROM   uk_order      o
   JOIN   uk_order_item oi ON oi.orderid = o.id
   WHERE  o.orderstatus = 'Incomplete'

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT model, order_quantity AS quantity_ordered
   FROM   f_order       o
   JOIN   f_order_item  oi ON oi.orderid = o.id
   WHERE  o.orderstatus = 'Incomplete'
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

But I doubt it will be faster.

And my standing advice is *not* to use CaMeL case identifiers in Postgres, quoted or not. Makes your life easier.

Comment: Thank you Erwin.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the tables as is.  As for CaMel, no worries, it's only for the example but yes, point taken.  I'm no SQL expert but your answer looks so straight forward (amost wants to make me bang my head against a wall and say out loud, DUH).  :D

Comment: @user3801108: My query was missing a table alias. Also added the simple alternative, which may be faster.

Comment: Erwin, perfect answer.  Can't vote up for some reason - 15 reputation? Yup, I'm new to Stack...  Many thanks again for your quick response. Sai.

Comment: @Sai-LeungLee: You can't upvote as new user, yet ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)), but you can always [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it actually answers your question.